# cmake: 'add_custom_target' - using 'file' command

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to create a custom target which should be used to cleaning out the output of my program.
Is it possible to do something like this:

```
    add_custom_target(
        clean_output
        file(REMOVE_RECURSE ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/output)
    )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following:

```
add_custom_target(
    clean_output
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E rm -rf "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/output"
)
```

Comment: This does not work for removing `.ninja_log`, when cmake is used with ninja instead of make. cmake appears to forcibly repopulate this file after every cmake target.